# Jenkins slave computer: executing an exe which needs to access a network drive fails

Tags: jenkins

In my slave computer, I have an exe that needs, among other things, to access a file on a network drive.
When running this exe from the slave computer, it works fine.
But, when I run it from Jenkins master computer, when it gets to the stage that it needs to access the network drive, it fails with "Access to the path {network path} is denied".

Both master and slave computers are Windows.

Any tips or suggestions? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Edit the "share" permissions of the network drive (from the server where the drive exists on) and make sure that "Everyone" has "change access".

Example:
[image]